# How to get text from the node in xml file, that contains text and child node?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader, xmlnode

I have a very big xml file. I read it using by xmlReader. I have problem when i reach to next line:

```
<title>Abasia<nemod>(-astasia) (hysterical)</nemod></title>
```

How I can read all that content. I have to have next string at the end:
"Abasia (-astasia) (hysterical)".

I tried to use ReadElementContentAsString() for all elements, but elements like this has exception, because it has child element.

help, please=)

Comment: Guys, i still need that help... Please, XML-experts=)

Comment: Have you tried using XPath instead of XmlReader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could something like this work for you?

```
XmlNodeList itemNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/");
XmlNode titleNode = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("title");
XmlNode nemodNode = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("nemod");
if((titleNode != null) && (dateNode != null))
    Console.WriteLine(titleNode.InnerText + " " + nemodNode.InnerText);
```

Comment: Does that make more sense to you? Sorry if I'm not helping a lot.

Comment: Yes. I did a little bit different way, but i got some info from that. Thanks=)