# Match text node in element with sub elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am having the same problem as described in
[How to get text from the node in xml file, that contains text and child node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659546/how-to-get-text-from-the-node-in-xml-file-that-contains-text-and-child-node)
but I need XSLT to match the text.

I have the following simplified XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>2013-09-02T00:00:00COPY
<contentVersion>
    <versionIdentification>2.1.1</versionIdentification>
</contentVersion>
</order>
```

I have tried the following XPATHs:

```
<xsl:variable name="vtextPostM" select="text()[self::order]"/>
<xsl:variable name="vtextPostM" select="self::text()[1]"/>
<xsl:variable name="vtextPostM" select="text()[self::*]"/>
```

I am expecting:

```
2013-09-02T00:00:00COPY
```

Comment: what's the context?  can you post your whole xslt path?  what xslt processor are you using?  a reproducible example would really help.  If you are interested in the 2013... string, why did you include the contentVersion node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where exactly are you when you define the variable? Without any context, the absolute path:

```
/order/text()[1]
```

or just (using your specific example):

```
/order/text()
```

should produce the result you want. You will want to wrap this in a normalize-space(), because it includes the trailing line feed before `<contentVersion>`.

Comment: Hello Michael, thank you. I will go with your solution. My mistake was that I did not consider the current node (order) properly in my XPATHs. Lesson learnt. Best regards, PEter

Answer (score 2):

Whoops, just edited my answer:

```
<xsl:variable name="vtextPostM" select="order/child::node()[position()=1][self::text()]"/>
```

Comment: No, you can't.  The `child::*` axis does not include text nodes.

Comment: but why did `<xsl:variable name="vtextPostM" select="order/child::*[position()=1][self::text()]"/>` and `<xsl:template match="contentVersion"><xsl:value-of select="$vtextPostM"/></xsl:template>` produced the wanted text node if that is not selected?

Comment: I'm sorry, of course `child::*` does include text nodes (unlike `*`).

Comment: Although it may not be apparent in the given example, there *is* a difference between "the first text node" and "the first node, provided it is text".

Comment: Thank you Joel for your solution - it works perfectly (+1). I will go with the one from Michael though because I do not need the check for position. Thank you, Peter